# creating a new matrix from a cell array after evaluating one column.

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array of 447*1 Dimensions. The cell array has 2Dimensional arrays of different dimensions of type double. I want to check a particular value in that cell array compare and on that basis store it in a new Matrix.

So for example my my starting cell array is Y{447*1} . My first cell contains an array of 
5*10 and second array contains data of 22*10 . I want to evaluate the second column
of this array and then store it in a new Matrix.

I did this for one set of data and the code looks something like this.

```
A = [y{2,1}(1:20,2),y{4,1}(1:20,2),y{6,1}(1:20,2),y{8,1}(1:20,2),...
    y{10,1}(1:20,2),y{12,1}(1:20,2),y{14,1}(1:20,2),y{16,1}(1:20,2),...
    y{18,1}(1:20,2),y{20,1}(1:20,2),y{22,1}(1:20,2),y{24,1}(1:20,2),...
    y{26,1}(1:20,2),y{28,1}(1:20,2),y{30,1}(1:20,2)];
```

But I want to automate the thing. Please help how this can be done.

Comment: I didn't understand could you please explain some more, and post the whole code.

Comment: The second column of a 5-by-10 matrix is 5-by-1. The second column of a 22-by-10 matrix is 22-by-1. Obviously, you can't concatenate these into a new matrix, so...could you clarify your question a bit? Please post(part of) your input, and your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
Temp = cellfun(@(x) x(1:20,2),Y(1:2:end,1), 'UniformOutput', false);
A = cat(2,Temp{:});
```

Should work if I am reading your question right - it should replicate your example anyway.
You can then change the dimensions of the @(x) function x(1:20,2) to take out different values from your cell array, and use different cell indexing for Y(:,1) to pick different parts of Y.